# How can I connect to a MySQL server on another computer?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-error-1064

Here I have some problem to connect to a MySQL server from another computer to my computer. I would like to use VB.net C# language to solve the problem.

Previously I used the following program to connect to a MySQL server from another computer to my computer, but this is not working anymore. Can anyone help me?

```
server = "192.168.8.124";
database = "Testing";
uid = "";
password = "1234";
string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3306 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
mycon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Comment: What does not work? What error message do you get?

Comment: have you tried to basics like pinging the IP to see if you can connect. Then trying to connect via VB database explorer?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what kind of error you get but try to check the IP Address of your computer and the other computer again. If your using a wireless to obtain the the IP Address make sure its static not dynamic.

For more info about static and dynamic ip address see this [Link](https://support.google.com/fiber/answer/3547208?hl=en)